# Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: - Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes

We have upgraded our Kubernates Service cluster on Azure to latest version 1.12.4. After that we suddenly  recognize that pods and nodes cannot communicate between anymore by private ip :

```
kubectl get pods -o wide -n kube-system -l component=kube-proxy
NAME               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
kube-proxy-bfhbw   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.4     aks-agentpool-16086733-1
kube-proxy-d7fj9   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.35    aks-agentpool-16086733-0
kube-proxy-j24th   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.97    aks-agentpool-16086733-3
kube-proxy-x7ffx   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.128   aks-agentpool-16086733-4
```

As you see the node aks-agentpool-16086733-0 has private IP 10.0.4.35 . When we try to check logs on pods which are on this node we got such error:

> Get
>   https://aks-agentpool-16086733-0:10250/containerLogs/emw-sit/nginx-sit-deploy-864b7d7588-bw966/nginx-sit?tailLines=5000&timestamps=true: dial tcp 10.0.4.35:10250: i/o timeout

We got the Tiller ( Helm) on this node as well, and if try to connect to tiller we got such error from Client PC:

> shmits-imac:~ andris.shmits01$ helm version Client:
>   &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3",
>   GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e",
>   GitTreeState:"clean"} Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading
>   connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.4.35:10250: i/o
>   timeout

Does anybody have any idea why the pods and nodes lost connectivity by private IP ?

Comment: pretty sure you need a support ticket. did you try rebooting nodes? can you check kube-proxy logs? according to people usually its docker daemon is broken on nodes

Comment: yes did reboot, and check logs , nothing there

Comment: can nodes talk to each other? can node talk to the pods on it?

Comment: I can not login on pod because got the same error dial tcp 10.0.4.35:10250: i/o

Comment: just login to the node, not the pod...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , after we scaled down the cluster from 4 nodes to 2 nodes problem disappeared. And after we again scaled up from 2 nodes to 4 everything started working fine

Answer (score 0):

issue could be with apiserver. did you check logs from apiserver pod?

can you run the below command inside cluster. do you 200 OK response?
curl -k -v https://10.96.0.1/version

Comment: andris_shmits@Azure:~$ curl -k -v https://10.96.0.1/version
*   Trying 10.96.0.1....
No reply

Comment: What is the clusterIP from the following command ( kubectl get svc| grep kubernetes )

Comment: shmits-imac:~ andris.shmits01$ kubectl get svc| grep kubernetes
kubernetes                                       ClusterIP      10.0.8.1      <none>           443/TCP                      223d
kubernetes-certbot                               LoadBalancer   10.0.8.219    13.81.13.65      80:31530/TCP                 21d

Comment: 10.0.8.1 is your apiserver internal IP address. try ( curl -k -v https://10.0.8.1/version )

Answer (score 0):

These issues come when nodes in the Kubernetes cluster created using kubeadm do not get proper Internal IP addresses matching with Nodes/Machines IP.

**Issue**: If I run helm list command from my cluster then I get below error

```
helm list
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: unable to upgrade connection: pod does not exist
```

kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k-master     Ready    master   3h10m   v1.18.5   10.0.0.5      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-58-generic   docker://19.3.12
k-worker01   Ready    <none>   179m    v1.18.5   10.0.0.6      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-58-generic   docker://19.3.12
k-worker02   Ready    <none>   167m    v1.18.5   10.0.2.15     <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-58-generic   docker://19.3.12
```

Please note: k-worker02 has internal IP as 10.0.2.15 but I was expecting 10.0.0.7 which is my node/machine IP.

**Solution:**

- Step 1: Connect to Host ( here k-worker02) which does have expected IP
- Step 2: open below file

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

- Step 3: Edit and append with --node-ip 10.0.0.7

code snippet

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --node-ip 10.0.0.7
```

- Step 4: Reload the daemon and restart the kubelet service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

**Result**:

kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k-master     Ready    master   3h36m   v1.18.5   10.0.0.5      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-58-generic   docker://19.3.12
k-worker01   Ready    <none>   3h25m   v1.18.5   10.0.0.6      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-58-generic   docker://19.3.12
k-worker02   Ready    <none>   3h13m   v1.18.5   10.0.0.7      <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS   4.15.0-58-generic   docker://19.3.12
```

With the above solution, the k-worker02 node has got expected IP (10.0.07) and "forwarding ports:" error stops coming from "helm list or helm install commnad".

Reference: https://networkinferno.net/trouble-with-the-kubernetes-node-ip